# how to customize class for imagebutton panel?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have made one simple button panel.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:id="@+id/buttonpanel">
  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonhome"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/homeselector"
               android:focusable="true">
               </ImageButton>
  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonsearch"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/searchselector"
               android:focusable="true">
               </ImageButton>>
  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonreg"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/registerselector"
               android:focusable="true">
               </ImageButton>>
  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonlogin"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/loginselector"
               android:focusable="true">
               </ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>`

Now my problem is that i am using it in my entire app.suppose i have 4 activity class that includes this panel.

**so i have to write the below  code number of times as activity classess.**

```
buttonhome=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonhome);
    buttonhome.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonsearch=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonsearch);
    buttonsearch.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonreg=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonreg);
    buttonreg.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonlogin=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
    buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(this);

}
public void onClick(View view)
{
    int id=view.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.buttonhome:
        break;
    case R.id.buttonsearch:
        break;
    case R.id.buttonreg:
        break;
    case R.id.buttonlogin:
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent("com.coupon.main.couponmandi.Login"));
        break;
    }
```

so is there any way that i can make one single class that handles all things.

thankx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that implements the clicklistener, and put all the above codes there. In each activity, construct that class.

```
public class ButtonHandler implements OnClickListener{
    private Activity mContext;
    public ButtonHandler(Activity context){
       mContext=context;

       buttonhome=(ImageButton)mContext.findViewById(R.id.buttonhome);
       buttonhome.setOnClickListener(this);
       ...
    }

    ...
}
```